# Change Material TextInputLayout stroke color in dropdown state

Tags: android, material-design, autocompletetextview, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I'm using `TextInputLayout` with `AutoCompleteTextView` to show a list of items in a dropdown view.

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilCategoriesDropdown"
                style="@style/DropdownTextInputLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:endIconMode="dropdown_menu"
                app:hintEnabled="false">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/actvCategoriesDropdown"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/MyTextStyle"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:inputType="none" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Style

```
<style name="DropdownTextInputLayout" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/color_dropdown_box_stroke</item> // P.s. not sure what what states should be specified in color selector
    ...
</style>
```

Color state list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:color="@color/carbon_green_500" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/carbon_red_600" android:state_focused="false" />
    <item android:color="@color/carbon_red_600" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/carbon_red_600"/>
  </selector>
```

**Question:** How can I achieve having different colors of the stroke around the `TextInputLayout` view in states where the dropdown list is **shown/hidden.** ex: green color of the stroke when the dropdown list is show and red when it's hidden. I've tried different combinations of color selectors with different states but couldn't achieve the result I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to put app:endIconTint

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilCategoriesDropdown"
            style="@style/DropdownTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:endIconMode="dropdown_menu"
            app:endIconTint="@color/white"
            app:hintEnabled="false">

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/actvCategoriesDropdown"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/MyTextStyle"
                android:editable="false"
                android:inputType="none" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```